# Retrieving the list of products just after the order is placed

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I want to get the list of products from the order within the hook **actionObjectOrderAddAfter** however the function **$order->getProducts()** returns an empty array. Calling the same function from a different hook (for example **hookAdminOrder**) works fine. What am I missing?
Thanks

```
public function hookActionObjectOrderAddAfter($params)
{
    $order_id = $params['object']->id;
    $order = new Order((int) $order_id);
    $products = $order->getProducts()
    
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. In this hook you need to get the products from the cart - not from the order itself.

```
public function hookActionObjectOrderAddAfter($params)
{
$order_id = $params['object']->id;
$order = new Order((int) $order_id);
$cart = new Cart((int) $order->id_cart);
$products = $cart->getProducts()

/*
...
*/
}
```